# Точность после точки double переменной

Tags: c++, double, точность

Есть переменная `double num` и переменная `int capacity`

Не могу найти способ настроить точность числа `num` в зависимости от переменной `capacity` и распространялось на все приложение. То есть, если `capacity = 3` тогда может иметь только такой вид:`num = 2.345`.

`setprecision(num)` - не подходит.

**заранее спасибо**.

Comment: Для вывода? Добавьте еще `<< fixed`. А для использования в программе - ну, все равно точно не получится из-за специфики представления... но приближенно - `num = round(num*1000)/1000.;` - где 1000 - просто 10 в степени `capacity`. А вообще - задайте вопрос точно..

Comment: @Harry Есть ли способ чтоб форматировать само число? fixed - нужно обьявлять один раз или перед каждым выводом?

Comment: Можно так -- `printf("%.*f\n", capacity, num);`  (вообще, читайте [man fprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf))